# InnoDB not doing Index Merge

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE values (
    id int(10) auto_increment NOT NULL, 
    molecule_id int(5) NOT NULL,
    descriptor_id int(5) NOT NULL,
    T double DEFAULT NULL,
    value double NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY index1 (molecule_id, T),
    KEY index2 (descriptor_id, T)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Rows of the table are many combinations of 3000 descriptor_ids, 600 molecule_ids and 3500 Ts with random double values (about 2 billion rows).

I was under the impression that for a query like

```
SELECT T, value FROM values WHERE molecule_id = X AND descriptor_id = Y
```

mysql would use both keys and then intersect the results. But doing an `Explain extended` on this query tells me it only uses index2, having chosen between index1 and index2.

molecule_id = X hits about 1/600 of the table.
descriptor_id = Y hits either a very small part of the table  of the table (like 0.001%) or about 1/700, depending on Y.

It seems like intersecting would be faster than just using index2 and scanning the rest of the over ~2.5 million rows. Even if the 3000 descriptor_ids were evenly distributed it would still leave 800,000 rows to scan on average.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spencer7593 has it right. An index_merge only occurs in range situations. If your `AND` were an `OR` it would trigger an index_merge. However, since it is an `AND`, why not make a multi_column index on both `molecule_id` and `descriptor_id`? That will get you better results, and faster. If `descriptor_id` is more exclusive (as you mentioned) do this:

`ALTER TABLE values ADD INDEX descriptor_molecule (descriptor_id, molecule_id, T, value)`

As long as your query has both columns in the where clause with an `AND` condition, it will use this index. In this case, I would actually drop your `index2`, since if the query only has the `descriptor_id` column in the where clause, it can still use the `descriptor_molecule` index as a prefix index. Plus, indexing all 4 columns will create a covering index for the query you mentioned and thus speed up your query by quite a bit.

Comment: A covering index would probably give even better performance `(descriptor_id, molecule_id, T, value)`. (I was going to suggest an index (like you did) in your answer, but I stopped short of there, and just answered the question about why we would not expect MySQL to do an `index merge` operation.

Comment: The problem is, every combination of descriptor_id, molecule_id, T is possible in a query, even with ranges. And a query like `SELECT * FROM values WHERE descriptor_id = X AND molecule_id BETWEEN Y AND Z` still doesn't merge and can't use an index like (molecule_id,descriptor_id). So if I wanted to cover every possibility with best performance, I would need 6 indexes, wouldn't I? Also, can someone explain to me this blog entry? It seems to me, it does an intersection of two single column indexes in the third listing on a query like the one I posted in my question.

Comment: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/09/19/multi-column-indexes-vs-index-merge/

Comment: Never mind, found this condition in the manual that I must have  missed before. "This access algorithm can be employed when a WHERE clause was converted to several range conditions on different keys combined with AND, and each condition is one of the following:

    In this form, where the index has exactly N parts (that is, all index parts are covered):

    key_part1=const1 AND key_part2=const2 ... AND key_partN=constN". If I had two seperate one column indexes, it would indeed intersect, but because in my table the indexes are multi column it can't use them to intersect.

Comment: Adding `T, value` to the index index of `descriptor_id, molecule_id` would be good. I was out of it when I wrote my response and was trying to figure out what the `T` was (I didn't see the column `T`). I was presuming a covering index with my answer though, yes. And as you mentioned, if you introduce a range lookup, it obviously is going to stop using your index at that column. There are going to be cases where you are going to need multiple indices based on your queries.

Answer (score 0):

I believe an `index_merge` operation will only be used when there is a range scan on at least one of the keys. Your sample query has only equality predicates, nothing the MySQL sees as a range scan.